# Qual a unidade de medida das medidas CSS no react-native

Tags: react-native

Ao criar um aplicativo coloquei os botões acertando pelo CSS com o layout, porém agora tenho que criar imagens para colocar no lugar destes botões.

Foi ai que me surgiu uma grande dúvida, pois as medidas do botão são:

```
botao: {
  width: 140, 
  height: 140, 
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  marginBottom: 20,
},
```

Porém esse 140 representa qual medida? 140px? Qual as medidas que devo usar na imagem?

Comment: `React-Native` não utiliza `CSS`

Comment: Então qual o nome dessas medidas?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

Comment: Quando programamos em `Kotlin` (por exemplo) usamos `dp` e não `px`, o que, se não me engano, é o caso do `React Native` e `NativeScript`.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada sobre o dp aqui, e este seria para converter a imagem a proporção definida dependendo da densidade de pixels da tela, é isso?

Comment: E nesse caso então não haveria um valor exato, pois depende do aparelho

Comment: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html

Traduzindo:

> Todas as dimensões no React Native são adimensionais (sem unidade de medida) e representam **pixels independentes de densidade (resolução)**.

O fator que multipla as unidades de medida e dá origem aos valores em pixel reais é chamada de *pixel ratio* pois é sempre a razão (*ratio*) entre duas densidades de pixels. Você pode obtê-lo através do método `PixelRatio.get()` (fonte: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html).

---

Exemplificando como é o cálculo de *pixel ratio*, em sistemas Android existem seis densidades:

- `ldpi`: 120 dpi
- `mdpi`: 160 dpi
- `hdpi`: 240 dpi
- `xhdpi`: 320 dpi
- `xxhdpi`: 480 dpi
- `xxxhdpi`: 640 dpi

Uma unidade de medida no React Native equivale a exatamente `1 px` em `mdpi` e para as demais resoluções você pode multiplicar pela razão entre a densidade de pixels da resolução atual e a densidade da resolução em `mdpi`. Assim, `1` equivaleria a `1 × 480 dpi/160 dpi px` = `3 px` em `xxhdpi` pois a *pixel ratio* é `480 dpi/160 dpi` = `3`.

Para iOS, a resolução padrão é de `163 dpi` e as demais são múltiplos inteiros dela. Assim, `1` pode equivaler a `1 px`, `2 px`, `3 px` etc.